# In Django Rest Framework, how do I serialize values to an arraylist?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework 3.0+,I want get this value:

```
{
  image:[img1,img2,img3]
}
```

and my code like:

models.py

```
class UserDynamic(models.Model):

    """User dynamic"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class UserDynamicImage(models.Model):

    """User dynamic images"""
    userdynamic = models.ForeignKey(UserDynamic)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='UserDynamicImage/')
```

serializers.py

```
class UserDynamicImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.image

class UserDynamicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserProfileSerializer()
    imgs = serializers.SerializerMethodField('GetImage')
    # imgs = serializers.ListField(img = serializers.ImageField())
    # imgs = UserDynamicImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserDynamic
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'content', 'imgs', 'createtime')

    def GetImage(self,UserDynamic):
        entity = UserDynamicImage.objects.filter(userdynamic = UserDynamic)
        return UserDynamicImageSerializer(entity,many=True,context={"request": self.context['request']}).data
```

Right now，it return a error:
 is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

In your `UserDynamicImageSerializer` instead of returning `obj.image` return `obj.image.url`

you can do like:

```
class UserDynamicImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if obj.image:
            return obj.image.url
```

Another way to do this without using `UserDynamicImageSerializer`:

```
class UserDynamicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserProfileSerializer()
    imgs = serializers.SerializerMethodField('GetImage')

    class Meta:
        model = UserDynamic
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'content', 'imgs', 'createtime')

    def GetImage(self,UserDynamic):
        entity = UserDynamicImage.objects.filter(userdynamic=UserDynamic).values_list('image',flat=True)
        return entity
```

Comment: Sorry,throw a error: `child` is a required argument. and I Add chind arg. It throw :'Store_Rotation' object is not iterable.